# Create a full screen div with next / previous links

Tags: jquery, html, css

How would I go about creating a full screen div with next / previous links where clicking the next link scrolls to the next page and clicking the previous link scrolls to the previous page.  Please see my code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next").click(function(event) {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("html, body").stop().animate({
      scrollTop: y + $(window).height()
    }, 800);
  });
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#app {
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

#pages {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}


/*************************************************************************************************/


/* Prev & next button styling                                                                    */


/*************************************************************************************************/

p {
  font-size: 0;
  /* Fixes inline block spacing */
}

span {
  /*border: 1px solid #fff;*/
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span.align-left {
  left: 0%;
  text-align: left;
}

span.align-right {
  right: 0%;
  text-align: right;
}

span.align-left,
span.align-right {
  top: 50%;
  position: fixed;
}

span a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.prev {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.next {
  background-color: #ed6e0f;
  color: white;
}

.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Website - Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="pages">
      <p>
        <span class="align-left">
      <a href="#" class="prev round">&#8249;</a>
     </span>
        <span class="align-right">
      <a href="#" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
     </span>
      </p>

      <div class="page">
        Our&nbsp;Services
      </div>
      <div class="page">
        Menu&nbsp;Examples
      </div>
      <div class="page">
        Book&nbsp;Your&nbsp;Chef
      </div>
      <div class="page">
        Contact&nbsp;Us
      </div>
      <div class="page">
        Live&nbsp;Feed
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Preferably I would only like the 1st div with the .page class to be active and visible until I click the next link which will hide the current div and scroll the next div with class .page into view.

Cheers,

Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created very simple functions to do what you want. I tried to start from your code so it's more simple for you (I hope) to understand what happens.

I created a loop (when you arrive at the end of your pages and click to "next button", you start from the first page) and I added 2 functions to set on the top of the browser windows the last page you clicked when you resize the page (you can remove them if you don't care about this staff).

So this is my code, enjoy it! ;)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

      var myPage=1;
      var totPages=$(".page").length;

      scroll(myPage); /* This put the page 1 on the top of the window when you visit for the first time the web page.*/

      $(".next, .prev").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if($(this).hasClass("next")){
          myPage = (myPage==totPages) ? 1 : myPage+1;
        } else{
          myPage = (myPage==1) ? totPages : myPage-1; 
        } 

        scroll(myPage);
      });


      function scroll(nextPage){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("div[data-id='"+nextPage+"']").offset().top
        }, 800);
      }

      /* These 2 functions put the last page you clicked on the top when you resize
      browser window. You can remove them if you do not care this stuff*/

      var resize;
      $(window).resize(function() {
        clearTimeout(resize);
        resize = setTimeout(resizeStuff, 200);
      });
      
      function resizeStuff() {
        scroll(myPage);
      }

    });
```

```css
   body,
    html,
    #pages,
    #app,
    .page {
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    #app {
      background-color: #dcdcdc;
    }

  


    /*************************************************************************************************/


    /* Prev & next button styling                                                                    */


    /*************************************************************************************************/

    p {
      font-size: 0;
      /* Fixes inline block spacing */
    }

    span {
  /*border: 1px solid #fff;*/
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

span.align-left {
  left: 0%;
  text-align: left;
}

span.align-right {
  right: 0%;
  text-align: right;
}

span.align-left,
span.align-right {
  top: 50%;
  position: fixed;
}

span a {
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.prev {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.next {
  background-color: #ed6e0f;
  color: white;
}

.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div id="pages">
      <p>
        <span class="align-left">
            <a href="#" class="prev round">&#8249;</a>
          </span>
        <span class="align-right">
            <a href="#" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
          </span>
      </p>

      <div class="page" data-id="1" style="background-color:#ff0000;">
        Our&nbsp;Services
      </div>
      <div class="page" data-id="2" style="background-color:#00ff00;">
        Menu&nbsp;Examples
      </div>
      <div class="page" data-id="3" style="background-color:#0000ff;">
        Book&nbsp;Your&nbsp;Chef
      </div>
      <div class="page" data-id="4" style="background-color:#ffff00;">
        Contact&nbsp;Us
      </div>
      <div class="page" data-id="5" style="background-color:#123456;">
        Live&nbsp;Feed
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In addition, I'll point out this beautiful, very complete jquery plugin that can help you develop what you want: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js

Cheers ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for the code and plugin, the code is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, and will definitely check out the plugin.

Comment: Glad to have helped you, Tim. :)